# How can I get rid of the "Can't locate object method "warn" via package "sssself" error in IE::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, hashref

I'm playing around with the Win32::IE::Mechanize. I'm trying a script to automatically access six of my web-based email accounts. The script basically works but perl throws a kind of cryptic "Can't locate object method "warn" via package "sssself" (perhaps you forgot to load " sssself)" error. Despite the error, the script can still get the job done. But I want to get rid of it and understand why it is happening. The following is the script. Please kindly commment where I can improve the code. Thanks like always.

```
use strict;
use Win32::IE::Mechanize;


my @accounts = (
'http://mail.21cn.com',
'frmmail1',
    {
        'Username' => 'myusername',
        'passwd' => 'mypassword',
        },
'http://mail.126.com',
'form',
    {
        'user' => 'myusername',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        },
......
......
......
    );

sub arg{
shift (@accounts);
}

while(@accounts){
my $mech = Win32::IE::Mechanize->new(visible=>1);
my $url = arg;
my $form = arg;
my $account = arg;

$mech->get($url);
$mech->form_name($form);
eval {$mech->set_fields(%$account);}; 
warn $@ if $@;
$mech->click();
}
```

I know something is wrong with the line

```
$mech->set_fields(%$account);
```

But how can I correct it? or should I just delete

```
warn $@ if $@;
```

and pretend there's nothing wrong?

Any comments are welcome :)

**UPDATE**

Thank you, @daotoad, for cleaning up of my ugly code :) I think the nested structure is much more maintainable and nice on the eyes.

and thank you, @Eric, for pointing me to a better version of the module in question :)

Well, the thing is when Win32::IE:Mechanize 0.009 gives the following cryptic error message

> Can't locate object method "warn" via
>   package "sssself" (perhaps you forgot
>   to l oad "sssself"?) at
>   C:/Perl/site/lib/Win32/IE/Mechanize.pm
>   line 971.

the 0.009_17 Dev Release gives me some very very meaningful message:

> No inputcontrol by the name 'Username'
>   at E:\mailme.pl line 33

With this error message in mind, I checked the source file of the login page and it has turned out that the field id should be "UserName", instead of "Username".

So I fixed my problem :)
Thank you guys!

Comment: Mike, I'm glad you found the error.  The clean up might have helped, ssssself might have come from inside your data structure. In this case it didn't.  Actually, reminds me of one of the ways I know I'm tired and need to stop coding: when I blink and find that I've typed something like `sub foo { my $f = ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssshift`  Oops.  Nap-time.

Comment: @daotaod, lol, naptime, that makes sense :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that there is an error in Win32::IE::Mechanize version 0.009.  There is a [developer release 0.009_17](http://search.cpan.org/~abeltje/Win32-IE-Mechanize/lib/Win32/IE/Mechanize.pm) that may work better.  I haven't tested it, but at least the 'sssself' is fixed.  If IE isn't a requirement, there is also `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` and `WWW::Mechanize` if the browser isn't needed.

Comment: FWIW the "new" development release of Win32::IE::Mechanize is nearly 5 years old, so don't expect it to go stable anytime soon :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have time to give you are really good answer ATM, but here's a clean up of the code.  Take a look at the comments.  If you have any questions about what I did or why, just comment below and I'll update the question.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;  # Use warnings - see perldoc perllexwarn

use Try::Tiny;  # Don't try to handle your own exceptions.  Try::Tiny does it better.

use Win32::IE::Mechanize;

# Use a nested structure so you don't have to keep popping stuff off a global array.   
my @accounts = (

    {   url       => 'http://mail.21cn.com',
        form_id => 'frmmail1',
        fields => {
            Username   => 'myusername',
            passwd     => 'mypassword',
        }
    },
    {   url => 'http://mail.126.com',
        form_id => 'form',
        fields => {
            user => 'myusername',
            password => 'mypassword',
        },
    },
);

# No messing about with @accounts means we can use a for loop.
for my $account (@accounts) {

    # Its not necessary to unpack these into scalars.
    # It makes sense if you are going to transform the values or use them many times.
    my $url    = $account->{url};
    my $form   = $account->{form_id};
    my $fields = $account->{fields};

    my $mech = Win32::IE::Mechanize->new(visible=>1);

    $mech->get($url);
    $mech->form_name($form);

    # Exception handling redone with Try::Tiny    
    $mech->click() if try { 
        $mech->set_fields(%$fields);
        1;
    }
    catch {
        warn "Form failed - $_\n";
    };
}
```

Comment: @daotaod, thanks for the cleaning up of my ugly code. Thanks, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @daotoad, I'm trying to figure out why "Form failed" when it looks like nothing is wrong there and most importantly why when "Form failed", I can still access my mailboxes using the supposedly "failed form".

Comment: @daotaod, maybe it's a bug in IE::Mechanize?